# PowerBI Desktop and R Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'

Tags: r, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm really stuck and need some help.

After installing R 3.5.1, I'm getting this error message on R visualizations in Power BI Desktop which were previously working

> ```
>  "Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2': package
>  'scales' was installed by an R version with different internals; it
>  needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version."
> ```

I already tried to:

- reinstall R 3.5.1
- reinstall RStudio
- reinstall ggplot2 and scales package
- reinstall all packages
- reinstall Power BI Desktop

Still it does not work.

Considerations:

- My visualizations were working well before I installed R 3.5.1
- My visualizations are working well on other PCs
- When I run the code on RStudio I don't get any error

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you reinstalling ggplot2 & scales through RStudio, or R terminal? Have you tried to install with `dependencies=TRUE` for the installation?

Comment: I'm trying to reinstalling through RStudio. How can I install with those dependencies? Thanks

Comment: Just tried to reinstall them with `dependencies=TRUE`and still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I would try running this inside your visual:

```
.libPath()

library(ggplot2)
```

It will give you an error message but there should be the output of `.libPath()`  as well, looking like:

> ```
> [1] "C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.4"
>
> [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library"
> ```

and then I would try to install (or copy an existing folder) ggplot into one of those directories.